# Python3 - Passing a list to a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3, I'm currently trying to modify a list using a function. (By the way, VERY new to Python :) )

I'll show the directions for the problem, just as reference.

"Write a function called make_great() that modifies the list of magicians by adding the phrase 'the Great' to each magician's name. Call show_magicians() to see that the list has actually been modified."

```
magicians = ['larry', 'mo', 'curly', 'nate']

def printing_magicians(names):
    """Printing the magicians names"""
    for name in names:
        print(name.title())

printing_magicians(magicians)

def make_great(names):
    """Adding 'the Great' to each magician"""
    for name in names:
        print(names + " the Great")
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I don't understand what argument to call for the make_great() function, and then I don't understand how to apply a show_magicians() function to see the list that has been modified. Any help would be awesome! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to modify a list? All you've done is print things...

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to modify the list using a function by adding 'the Great' to each name. Should I be doing something different than "print(names + " the Great") after the 'for' loop?

Comment: Yes. `print` doesn't modify anything. It simply prints a value to the standard output. Likely, your console here.

Answer (score 3):

To modify a list in-place, you should reference each item of the list by its index:

```
def make_great(names):
    for i in range(len(names)):
        names[i] += " the Great"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's idiomatic in Python to loop over lists with `enumerate()` when you need the index. It will give you both the value and in the index into the list so you can:

```
def make_great(names):
    for i, name in enumerate(names):
        names[i] = f'{name} the Great'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method in one line. The basic idea is to use list comprehension and modify all the elements of the list by slicing `[:]`.

```
def make_great(names):
    """Adding 'the Great' to each magician"""
    names[:] = [name + ' the Great' for name in names]
```

The `show_magicians` function is to just print `magicians` since `magicians` variable is in the global scope.

```
def show_magicians():
    print(magicians)
```

Example:

```
>>> make_great(magicians)
>>> show_magicians()
['larry the Great', 'mo the Great', 'curly the Great', 'nate the Great']
```

Comment: Wow! Super helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this with `newNames` defined globally:

```
newNames = []
def make_great(names):
    for name in names:
        name += " the Great"
        newNames.append(name)
```

Then you can go ahead and print your new list by calling your function with `newNames` as your argument.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the `make_great` function to return the list you want, you can do:

```
def make_great(names):
    return [name + " the Great" for name in names]
```

Comment: Nitpick: This does not modify the list, but rather creates a new list with the expected values. If this is an assignment, this may not be an acceptable solution.

Comment: And then what would be the argument when I call the make_great() function?